# How to view all existing user of my system?

Tags: system, user

I am new to elementary OS as well as Linux and command-line. I have learned that some users are not listed in the system user accounts. How can I view them?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is normal for your system to have some system users and system users are usually not listed in the user accounts under system settings. To check them execute the following command in terminal,

```
sudo cat /etc/passwd
```

If you are currently logged in with the root account you can ignore the term `sudo` which is used to give a user superuser permission.